# PEP8 inspection when concatenating tuples of tuples

Tags: python, tuples, python-3.5

I'm concatenating tuples of tuples, for example:

```
a = 1, 2
b = 1, 2
ab = a, b

c = 1, 2
d = 1, 2, 3
cd = c, d

z = ab + cd
```

This obviously works as expected, but PEP8 code inspector (integrated in PyCharm) tags the last line with a *weak warning*:

> Expected type 'Tuple[Tuple[int, int], ...]' (matched generic type 'Tuple[_T_co, ...]'), got 'Tuple[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int, int]]' instead

I understand it's assuming I wish to concatenate pairs only, and the *d* tuple breaks such assumption. If I remove the last element in *d* or add extra elements to other tuples, PEP8 inspector doesn't complain.

I can disable that specific inspection for the line, but is there any other way to prevent PEP8 inspector from making assumptions about my intentions?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that inspector in PyCharm, but perhaps an explicit type annotation would help: `z: Tuple[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int, int]] = ...`. If it's not always 2 elements then 3 elements, you can use `Tuple[Tuple[int, ...], ...]` for a variable-length tuple of variable-length tuples.

Comment: When you put your cursor on the underlined part, PyCharm will offer you options to get rid of the warning. just chose one of them

Comment: @ScottColby Thank you. Your suggestion is exactly what I was asking for. I had never used annotations, but I'm going to take them seriously from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit annotation should solve this problem.

If you always have a tuple of a two-tuple and a three-tuple, you need:

```
z: Tuple[Tuple[int, int], Tuple[int, int, int]]
```

If you have a variable-length tuple of variable-length tuples, you need:

```
z: Tuple[Tuple[int, ...], ...]
```

The ellipsis literal `...` is quite an interesting part of Python's syntax. It is the same as the built-in `Ellipsis` constant and, besides its use in type annotations, can be used in custom slicing functionality. Some also use it as an alternative to `pass` as in

```
def stub_function():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the comment `# noinspection PyTypeChecker` right before the line of code you want Pycharm linter to ignore, like this:

```
# noinspection PyTypeChecker
z = ab + cd
```

Comment: I said I could disable the inspection for the line, so I was asking for a different option.

Comment: In term of options, you can disable this inspection for all python code you edit with pycharm, you can disable for a specific scope, etc. refer to [pycharm doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/suppressing-inspections.html) for further details

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my original question, I didn't want to disable the inspection.
And, after reading Scott Colby's suggestion, I started using type annotations, so my preferred solution is:

```
from typing import Tuple
MyTuple = Tuple[Tuple[int, ...], ...]

a = 1, 2
b = 1, 2
ab = a, b       # type: MyTuple

c = 1, 2
d = 1, 2, 3
cd = c, d       # type: MyTuple

z = ab + cd
```

As a general rule, instead of taking a painkiller (disabling the inspection) I prefer to be aware of the cause of my "disease" and to declare my intentions clearly.